# How to chainload winload.efi / exe from Grub2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, lubuntu, windows-10

I have a nice and running LUbuntu being booted in EFI by Grub2.

Now I want to chainload Windows 10 from another partition that I copied-over from another disk to the local partition. I want to have it booted directly by winload.efi without intermediary MS-Windows bootmanager BCD hassle.

Here is my `/etc-grub.d/40_custom` menu:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "MS-Windows 10" --class windows --class os {
        insmod chain
        insmod ntfs
        search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid 4E589F8E589F7405
        echo (${root})/Windows/System32/Boot
        ls (${root})/Windows/System32/Boot
        echo (${root})/Windows/System32/Boot/winload.efi
        chainloader /Windows/System32/Boot/winload.efi
}
```

Unfortunately when I select `MS-Windows 10` menu option I get:

```
(hd0,gpt4)/Windows/System32/Boot
pl-PL/ winload.efi winload.exe winresume.efi winresume.exe
(hd0,gpt4)/Windows/System32/Boot/winload.efi
error: cannot load image.

Press any key to continue...
```

and Grub cycles.

I am pretty sure that `winload.efi` is there, since when I drop to Grub2 command line and manually do

```
insmod ntfs
ls (hd0,gpt4)/Windows/System32/Boot
```

the files are there.

I think that winload.efi needs some arguments like `C:\Windows` or something similar that Windows Boot Manager takes from BCD and passes to winload.

1. What are the exact options to winload?
2. How to make it load Windows?

Comment: That's not correct procedure. For a start there has to be a Microsoft entry in the ESP, otherwise Windows won't boot. Secondly Windows has to boot initially from its boot manager *bootmgfw.efi* which grub hands over to it once you select Windows. Since *bootmgfw.efi* is an instruction entry in Window's BCD, which has to be present in the ESP, there's no way to avoid it.

Comment: Ok, I am now chaining `(hd0,gpt4)/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi` and getting `error: symlink type invalid (80000017)`. Apparently MS-Windows starts loading and complains about something...

Comment: Is sda4 your ESP? Otherwise your chainload must be to ESP partition where Windows has its boot files. Grub2's os-prober automatically creates correct entry. `sudo update-grub` But that only works if both are UEFI (or both old BIOS).

Comment: Nope. It is NTFS `C:\Windows` partition.

Comment: Similar question, years older, much more detailed, same result: https://superuser.com/questions/729264/is-it-possible-to-boot-windows-8-1-without-its-own-bootmanager